# Angular reactive form - Getting error while passing formArray to child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have nested reactive form with formGroup and formArray in it.
When I tried to pass nested formArray to child component I am getting the below error as

> FormArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Below is the parent form group

```
this.employeeForm= this.fb.group({
 employee: this.fb.group({
   name: [null],
   id: [null]
  }),
 address: this.fb.array({
   location: [null],
   city: [null]
 });
});
```

Parent Form component

```
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm">
  <app-address [address]="employeeForm.controls.address"></app-address>
</form>
```

Address child component html

```
<div [formArrayName]="address">
<div *ngFor="let item of address.controls;" [formGroupName]="i">
  <input type="text" formControlName="location">
</div>
</div>
```

Address child component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.scss']
})
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  @Input() address: FormArray;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The overall form values are working fine when I did console.log(this.employeeForm)
Please check and suggest.
Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: The error tries to say that `formGroup` and `formControlName` should be in the same template. Try using `ng-content` to use them in the same template.

Comment: Can you please provide a small example with the ng-content ?
My form model is really big and has more than 100 fields. So I broken down into multi components.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine.
The issue is where you are using a custom-component `app-address` for the child form-group.

Angular forms are not automatically registered when inside nested component. However you can workaround this by providing the outer FormGroup to the child component.

You should also be passing the `formGroup` instance along with control name to your custom component. And then create a form control under that `formGroup` in custom component. Your custom component will create the control virtually under the same `formGroup` that you have provided.

```
<app-address [address]="employeeForm.controls.identity" [formGroup]="yourFormGroup" [controlName]="controlName"></app-address>
```

In child component you can initialize the form:

```
ngOnInit() {
   let control: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
   this.formGroup.addControl(this.controlName, control);
}
```

Comment: My form model is really big and has more than 100 fields.And I broken down into multi components.
And from the above example lets assume that I am passing address formArray which has array of formGroup with many formControls(such as Line,City,Landmark, State, Country) How to pass each and every controlName to child component as per your example ? Thanks

Comment: You can just keep passing these info to all the child and their nested child as needed.You may post a stackblitz link for me to take a look.